# Insert a Text Element at Each First Position of a Comma Separated String

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function

I have a hashtags-input field ([Input Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nou2D.png)) that saves the inputs comma separated. Now the problem is that people don't always type in a "#". Thats why I want to add it in front of each entered word afterwards.

Unfortuntately I'm having trouble creating a function that lets you add a "#" before each word, while the string is comma separated (not an array).

Does anyone has any idea how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: please show code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

supposing your string is `hashtags`,
you could try

```js
var corrected = hashtags.split(',') // separate by comma
  .map( word => "#" + word ) // add # to all
  .join(',') // recreate the string
```

but you probably need to check if there is already a # sign so this is better

```js
var corrected = hashtags.split(',') // separate by comma
  .map( word => word[0] == "#" ? word : "#" + word ) 
     // add # to those who don't start with #
  .join(',') // recreate the string
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the following code:
   var corrected = hashtags.split(',');
        corrected.map( word => word[0] == "#" ? word : "#" + word );
        corrected.join(',');
        alert(corrected);
but it's not working unfortuntately. The alert shows the same input, nothing changed. Any idea?

Comment: you need to get the result of .map in a variable, you added `;` between the split() and the map that does not work

Comment: .map does not modify the array, but returns a new array, so does .join that returns a new string, keep the code as it is or add `var corrected2 = corrected.map...`

Comment: I'm sorry! I get it. Thanks for your response!